# std::thread and move in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, multithreading, move

I have an only-moveable class and a function who takes an object of this class by value.
The functions is called in a new thread:

```
void foo(MyClass a) {}

int main()
{
   MyClass a;
   std::thread t(&foo, std::move(a));
}
```

I get a compiler error, because of the missing copy-constructor of MyClass (I deleted him) and if I implement him the copy-constructor is called.

Obviously this is a bug and it compiles without copy-constructor in gcc.
Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

If the method needs ownership of `a`, pass it through the heap, preferably in a `shared_ptr`:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<MyClass> a) {}
 [...]

auto a_ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
std::thread t(foo, a_ptr);
```

Otherwise just pass it by reference:

```
void foo(MyClass& a) {}
 [...]

MyClass a;
std::thread(foo, std::ref(a));
```

Comment: shared_ptr is the only option in VS2013 - unique_ptr fails to build due to bugs :(